# Can I load JavaScript Functions on One page then redirect to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an old application that I can not modify in anyway including editing the HTML in anyway directly.  I had to create a redirect html page for people to load in order to always get everyone to the correct location.

Can I load a JavaScript on Page one, and keep it loaded?

I.E.

```
    <html>
       <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getMyAppProductID()
    {
       //Do the Java action to find the Product ID.
    }
    </ script>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
          <META http-equiv="refresh"         content="0;URL=http://MyAppURL.internalUrl.local/StartupScript.jsp">
          <title>Load...</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <p>Loading My App</p>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Then when I am looking at my application I want to be able to call the function I wrote.

IE.  I have a floating button that does the getMyAppProductID Function.

Comment: No, you cannot. Only resources loaded in the current page can be used.

Comment: The problem I have is that I need to be able to load an existing application and I can not get It to make any changes to it. (It is locked down)  Politics but anyway....   I am trying to figure out how I can pull a field from the active page on this old web application.

Comment: Without modifying the code of the old app, you cannot add anything to it. The caveat to that would be by using the querystring or session, but it would have to use a generic method of accessing both for that to work, which would be very unlikely considering how bad an idea it would be.

Comment: create a page "Hub", creating a layer on top of then, like a menu page, from which you can go to the old page or to any other new development you have done... it won't break anything because you will be redirecting or better navigating from it... You could also load the pages in divs inside your menu page. BUT, if what you need is to share data, things may get complicated...

Comment: Do you have an example of how to setup a "hub" page you can share?  I do not know the term HUB page and I am not sure what I am searching for.